# How to pass an interable list to a lambda function in Python?

Tags: python

The following works fine to drop column names that contain the string `basket` anywhere in the column name of the `df`, how can I modify the below code to pass a list of strings to be filtered out instead of just a single string?

```
banned_columns = ["basket","cricket","ball"]
condition = lambda col: "basket" in col
new_df = df.drop(*filter(condition, df.columns))
```

The above just filters `basket`. How can I filter out `basket`, `cricket` and `ball` from `df.columns` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check exclude all the columns that contain any of the banned words using the built-in `any()` [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
banned_columns = ["basket","cricket","ball"]
condition = lambda col: any(word in col for word in banned_columns)
new_df = df.drop(*filter(condition, df.columns))
```

Answer (score 3):

The built-in function [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) comes in handy here:

```
condition = lambda col: any(item in col for item in banned_columns)
```